# Нужно ли брать в кавычки слово "сосед" (применительно к острову)?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Прощальный день посвятил пешей прогулке на крохотный островок Дзёдо (Jodo), который соединен с соседом дамбой.

Comment: При первом прочтении воспринимается будто "сосед" - дамба. Лучше заменить на "соседним (островом)" или "_со своим_ соседом". Кавычки не нужны.

Comment: Если заменить на "соседним (островом)" - будет два повторения слова "остров" в одном предложении. Это не есть хорошо. А если заменить на со своим соседом дамбой" - получится опять-таки будто "сосед" - дамба.

Comment: Ничего плохого в "острове таком-то и соседнем острове" в одном предложении быть не может, но в нем нет и второго "острова", есть "островок". "Со своим соседом соединён дамбой" - да, надо переставлять слова, это в исходном предложении дамба "в соседи просится".

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что кавычки не нужны (приравняем остров к местности).

В толковом словаре Кузнецова:
**сосед**, -а; м.
3. Государство, **местность**, граничащие с другим государством, местностью; население их.
*Соседи с запада, с востока. Наш северный сосед — Финляндия. Япония — наш восточный сосед.*

*Кроме того, планируя поездку на крупнейший эстонский остров, составьте маршрут таким образом, чтобы успеть познакомиться и с его ближайшим соседом — островом Муху, с которым Сааремаа соединён дамбой, пролегающей через пролив.*